# Gingerbread's IPsec client and Cisco ASA

Tags: ipsec, android

Android Gingerbread has added support for true IPsec VPN, and I'm trying to get this to work with my Cisco ASA 5510 appliance. On the device, I've selected PSK v1 with Xauth as the connection method. I'm seeing "all IPsec SA proposals found unacceptable" when the device attempts to connect on the ASA's debug log, and the devices says "IKE negotiation failed". The transform-sets currently applied to my outside interface are ESP-AES-256-SHA, and ESP-AES-256-MD5. Does anybody know the correct transform-set that I need to apply to allow Android devices to connect?

Comment: Excuse me, what Android version do you have **exactly**? I have Gingerbread version 2.3.4 here (CyanogenMod 7.1.0.RC12) and no such **true** IPSec is supported (only L2TP-over-IPSec).

Comment: This is on a Motorola Atrix 4G on ATT. System Version: 4.5.91.MB860.ATT.en.US, Android Version 2.3.4, Build Number 4.5.91.

Comment: This update apparently supports true IPsec at AES-128, using either PSK or Certificate. I'm using it with PSK (group name/password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that perfect forward secrecy needed to be disabled.